# Не подгружаются данные из JSON с помощью Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

Есть приложение, которое подгружает данные из `JSON` и выводит их в `RecyclerView`. Сам файл `JSON` лежит на сайте, поэтому использую для получения данных `Retrofit2`. На Android вплоть до 8-й версии проблем не наблюдаю, а на Android 9 на эмуляторе и на реальном устройстве есть данная проблема. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

> Выдает: Нет доступа к сайту

ApiClient

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static final String URL = "http://test.ru";

    private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }

    public static ApiService getApiService() {
        return getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService.class);
    }

}
```

ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("/for_apps/fairy_tails/fairy_tails.json")
    Call<ItemList> getFairyTailsJSON();

}
```

ItemList

```
public class ItemList {

    @SerializedName("fairy_tails")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<Item> item = null;

    public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<Item> item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, ItemSendId {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private ArrayList<Item> itemList;
    private ItemsAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ***

        loadData();

    }


    private void loadData() {
        final ApiService api = ApiClient.getApiService();
        Call<ItemList> call = api.getFairyTailsJSON();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ItemList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ItemList> call, Response<ItemList> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    itemList = response.body().getItems();
                    adapter = new ItemsAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemList);
                    adapter.setItemSendId(MainActivity.this);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 1));
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Не удается найти данные для отображения", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ItemList> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Нет доступа к сайту", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Вот все что было в логах

> 2019-09-19 09:50:40.271 5548-5548/? I/.kidsfairytale: Not
>   late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on) 2019-09-19 09:50:40.291
>   5548-5548/? W/.kidsfairytale: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using
>   defaults: x86 2019-09-19 09:50:40.519 5548-5555/? E/.kidsfairytale:
>   Failed to send jdwp-handshake response.: Broken pipe 2019-09-19
>   09:50:40.773 5548-5548/? W/.kidsfairytale: JIT profile information
>   will not be recorded: profile file does not exits. 2019-09-19
>   09:50:40.776 5548-5548/? I/chatty: uid=10086(ru.app.kidsfairytales)
>   identical 10 lines 2019-09-19 09:50:40.776 5548-5548/?
>   W/.kidsfairytale: JIT profile information will not be recorded:
>   profile file does not exits. 2019-09-19 09:50:40.790 5548-5548/?
>   I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support 2019-09-19
>   09:50:40.790 5548-5548/? I/MultiDex: Installing application 2019-09-19
>   09:50:40.790 5548-5548/? I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex
>   support library is disabled. 2019-09-19 09:50:40.831 5548-5548/?
>   I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process 2019-09-19
>   09:50:40.938 5548-5564/? W/.kidsfairytale: Unsupported class loader
>   2019-09-19 09:50:40.943 5548-5564/? I/DynamiteModule: Considering
>   local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:310 2019-09-19 09:50:40.943
>   5548-5564/? I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 310 2019-09-19
>   09:50:40.945 5548-5564/? W/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version <
>   2, falling back to loadModule2 2019-09-19 09:50:40.951 5548-5568/?
>   I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:7 and remote module
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0 2019-09-19 09:50:40.951
>   5548-5568/? I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite 2019-09-19 09:50:40.982
>   5548-5548/? W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden method
>   Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets;
>   (light greylist, linking) 2019-09-19 09:50:40.982 5548-5548/?
>   W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden field
>   Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking) 2019-09-19
>   09:50:40.982 5548-5548/? W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden field
>   Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
>   2019-09-19 09:50:40.983 5548-5548/? W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
>   2019-09-19 09:50:40.983 5548-5548/? W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
>   2019-09-19 09:50:40.992 5548-5564/? W/.kidsfairytale: Unsupported
>   class loader 2019-09-19 09:50:41.033 5548-5564/? W/.kidsfairytale:
>   Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
>   2019-09-19 09:50:41.073 5548-5548/? W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   method
>   Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.073 5548-5548/?
>   W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden method
>   Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light
>   greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.152 5548-5571/? I/FA-Ads:
>   App measurement is starting up, version: 16250 2019-09-19 09:50:41.152
>   5548-5571/? I/FA-Ads: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop
>   log.tag.FA VERBOSE 2019-09-19 09:50:41.381 5548-5548/?
>   W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden method
>   Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic;
>   (light greylist, linking) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.493 5548-5548/?
>   D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using
>   platform default 2019-09-19 09:50:41.500 5548-5548/? W/.kidsfairytale:
>   Accessing hidden method
>   Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light
>   greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.500 5548-5548/?
>   W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden method
>   Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist,
>   reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.500 5548-5548/? W/.kidsfairytale:
>   Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.629
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/WebViewFactory: Loading
>   com.android.chrome version 69.0.3497.100 (code 349710017) 2019-09-19
>   09:50:41.635 5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/.kidsfairytale: The
>   ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library. 2019-09-19
>   09:50:41.679 5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time
>   to load native libraries: 11 ms (timestamps 6881-6892) 2019-09-19
>   09:50:41.689 5548-5582/ru.app.kidsfairytales E/cr_VariationsUtils:
>   Failed reading seed file
>   "/data/user/0/ru.app.kidsfairytales/app_webview/variations_seed_new":
>   /data/user/0/ru.app.kidsfairytales/app_webview/variations_seed_new (No
>   such file or directory) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.694
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/chromium:
>   [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(36)] Chromium logging enabled: level =
>   0, default verbosity = 0 2019-09-19 09:50:41.694
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native
>   library version number "69.0.3497.100", actual native library version
>   number "69.0.3497.100" 2019-09-19 09:50:41.712
>   5548-5583/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/cr_ChildProcLH: Create a new
>   ChildConnectionAllocator with package name = com.android.chrome,
>   sandboxed = true 2019-09-19 09:50:41.724
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing
>   chromium process, singleProcess=false 2019-09-19 09:50:41.792
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/chromium:
>   [INFO:aw_field_trial_creator.cc(54)] First-WebView-Experiment not
>   found 2019-09-19 09:50:41.912 5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden method
>   Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;->(Landroid/content/Context;I)V
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.912
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   method
>   Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;->logEvent(Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;)V
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.912
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   method
>   Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionStarted(I)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.912
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   method
>   Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(II)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.912
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   method
>   Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.912
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   method
>   Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextSelection;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.913
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   method
>   Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(III)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.913
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   method
>   Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(IIILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:41.960
>   5548-5608/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH
>   permission 2019-09-19 09:50:41.964 5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   E/Ads: Google Mobile Ads SDK initialization functionality unavailable
>   for this session. Ad requests can be made at any time. 2019-09-19
>   09:50:42.008 5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/Ads: This request is
>   sent from a test device. 2019-09-19 09:50:42.008
>   5548-5619/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/ConfigStore:
>   android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay
>   retrieved: 0 2019-09-19 09:50:42.009 5548-5619/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   I/ConfigStore:
>   android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay
>   retrieved: 0 2019-09-19 09:50:42.022 5548-5619/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe04fbda0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
>   2019-09-19 09:50:42.023 5548-5619/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe04fbda0: ver 3 1 (tinfo
>   0xcc95c630) 2019-09-19 09:50:42.025 5548-5619/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da 2019-09-19
>   09:50:42.025 5548-5619/ru.app.kidsfairytales E/eglCodecCommon:
>   glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da 2019-09-19 09:50:42.064
>   5548-5619/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized
>   profile 4 for video/hevc 2019-09-19 09:50:42.076
>   5548-5619/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported
>   profile 4 for video/mp4v-es 2019-09-19 09:50:42.082
>   5548-5619/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/cr_MediaCodecUtil: HW encoder for
>   video/avc is not available on this device. 2019-09-19 09:50:42.163
>   5548-5576/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/.kidsfairytale: The
>   ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library. 2019-09-19
>   09:50:42.168 5548-5576/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/zzdx: File
>   /data/user/0/ru.app.kidsfairytales/cache/1561154238473.dex not found.
>   No need for deletion 2019-09-19 09:50:42.217
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
>   2019-09-19 09:50:42.336 5548-5644/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4 2019-09-19 09:50:42.336
>   5548-5644/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
>   2019-09-19 09:50:42.339 5548-5644/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without... 2019-09-19
>   09:50:42.339 5548-5644/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap
>   behavior 0 2019-09-19 09:50:42.354 5548-5644/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe1d87280: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
>   2019-09-19 09:50:42.364 5548-5644/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1d87280: ver 3 1 (tinfo
>   0xc6aec3d0) 2019-09-19 09:50:42.365 5548-5644/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da 2019-09-19
>   09:50:42.365 5548-5644/ru.app.kidsfairytales E/eglCodecCommon:
>   glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da 2019-09-19 09:50:42.383
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached;
>   skipping layout 2019-09-19 09:50:42.386
>   5548-5574/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
>   2019-09-19 09:50:42.402 5548-5619/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xdff23aa0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
>   2019-09-19 09:50:42.403 5548-5619/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdff23aa0: ver 3 0 (tinfo
>   0xcc95c630) 2019-09-19 09:50:42.536 5548-5628/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings 2019-09-19 09:50:42.543
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   method Landroid/widget/AutoCompleteTextView;->doBeforeTextChanged()V
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:42.543
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   method Landroid/widget/AutoCompleteTextView;->doAfterTextChanged()V
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:42.543
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden
>   method Landroid/widget/AutoCompleteTextView;->ensureImeVisible(Z)V
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2019-09-19 09:50:42.599
>   5548-5644/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0xe1d87280: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xc6aec3d0) 2019-09-19 09:50:42.878
>   5548-5644/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0xe1d87280: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xc6aec3d0) 2019-09-19 09:50:42.906
>   5548-5665/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/cr_CrashFileManager:
>   /data/user/0/ru.app.kidsfairytales/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does
>   not exist or is not a directory 2019-09-19 09:50:42.909
>   5548-5644/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0xe1d87280: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xc6aec3d0) 2019-09-19 09:50:42.920
>   5548-5644/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0xe1d87280: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xc6aec3d0) 2019-09-19 09:50:43.313
>   5548-5628/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/Ads: SDK version:
>   afma-sdk-a-v15601000.15601000.0 2019-09-19 09:50:43.443
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached;
>   skipping layout 2019-09-19 09:50:43.451
>   5548-5644/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0xe1d87280: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xc6aec3d0) 2019-09-19 09:50:44.259
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/AutofillManager: No AutofillClient
>   for ru.app.kidsfairytales on context
>   androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication@4fd7ee6 2019-09-19 09:50:44.614
>   5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/Ads: GET LOCATION COMPILED
>   2019-09-19 09:50:44.739 5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   W/.kidsfairytale: Accessing hidden method
>   Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency()I (light greylist, reflection)
>   2019-09-19 09:50:44.749 5548-5548/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   I/ExoPlayerImpl: Init ExoPlayerLib/2.4.2 [generic_x86, Android SDK
>   built for x86, Google, 28] 2019-09-19 09:50:45.175
>   5548-5681/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/MetadataUtil: Skipped unknown
>   metadata entry: gsst 2019-09-19 09:50:45.175
>   5548-5681/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/MetadataUtil: Skipped unknown
>   metadata entry: gstd 2019-09-19 09:50:45.249
>   5548-5684/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained
>   2019-09-19 09:50:45.312 5548-5690/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/OMXClient:
>   IOmx service obtained 2019-09-19 09:50:45.324
>   5548-5693/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext:
>   0xc31e01a0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4 2019-09-19 09:50:45.330
>   5548-5693/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0xc31e01a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xc3103a10) 2019-09-19 09:50:45.332
>   5548-5693/ru.app.kidsfairytales E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize:
>   unknow param 0x000082da 2019-09-19 09:50:45.332
>   5548-5693/ru.app.kidsfairytales E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize:
>   unknow param 0x000082da 2019-09-19 09:50:45.333
>   5548-5693/ru.app.kidsfairytales E/EGL_emulation: eglQueryContext 32c0 
>   EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE 2019-09-19 09:50:45.334
>   5548-5693/ru.app.kidsfairytales E/EGL_emulation: tid 5693:
>   eglQueryContext(1861): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE) 2019-09-19
>   09:50:45.335 5548-5689/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/SurfaceUtils:
>   connecting to surface 0xc0f9a808, reason connectToSurface 2019-09-19
>   09:50:45.335 5548-5689/ru.app.kidsfairytales I/MediaCodec:
>   [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setting surface generation to 5681153
>   2019-09-19 09:50:45.335 5548-5689/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0xc0f9a808, reason
>   connectToSurface(reconnect) 2019-09-19 09:50:45.335
>   5548-5689/ru.app.kidsfairytales D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface
>   0xc0f9a808, reason connectToSurface(reconnect) 2019-09-19 09:50:45.336
>   5548-5690/ru.app.kidsfairytales E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder]
>   setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -1010
>   2019-09-19 09:50:46.250 5548-5679/ru.app.kidsfairytales W/AudioTrack:
>   Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume
>   control 2019-09-19 09:50:46.250 5548-5679/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   W/AudioTrack: See the documentation of AudioTrack() for what to use
>   instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback
>   use case 2019-09-19 09:50:46.272 5548-5689/ru.app.kidsfairytales
>   D/MediaCodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setting dataspace on output
>   surface to #104

Comment: Уберите эту портянку логов - вряд ли в ней есть что-то полезное, так как в `onFailure` вы не печатаете туда полученную ошибку (`t.printStackTrace();` - самый простой вариант). Скорее всего проблема та же: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600

Comment: http потому что

Comment: тоже начал копать в сторону https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted/50834600#50834600.. Спасибо за наводку